# An active access token must be used to query information about the current user with facebook-android-sdk:4.+

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working with

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'
```

I could say I (almost) copied and paste the code of

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group

android sdk tab.

then my code is it:

```
    public GraphResponse Get(String query)
    {
        final GraphResponse[] respuesta = new GraphResponse[1];
        /* make the API call */
        new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                query,
                null,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */

                        respuesta[0] =response;
                    }
                }
        ).executeAndWait();
return  respuesta[0];
    }
```

and query value is  `me?fields=id,name,picture`

I alwas get

```
{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","fbtrace_id":"BADDWWomMZw","code":2500}}
```

even if I `delete data` of my application in "application manager" in settings
and I loggin again, then I re-try and I got the same message.

I have changed now the value of query for `me`
and this works fine (but it does not return the data which I want)

Comment: It seems like getCurrentAccessToken is retuning an invalid token.  Have you tried generating a new one?

Comment: I delete data of my application and I loggin again (then I got a new Token), I checked in  explorer ( https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer ) and this works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved

```
me?fields=id,name,picture
```

not work because 
`?fields=id,name,picture` 
is not part of link, else they hay parameters  then, they are added with a bundle

```
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,picture");

 new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                query,
                parameters,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */

                        respuesta[0] =response;
                    }
                }
        ).executeAndWait();
```

then this works